# $ is not defined in Firefox using jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, firefox

I got this error in Firefox only, everything works perfectly well in IE and Chrome, I'm using Firefox v 15.0. Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       // some code here
    });
```

Exception occurs on first line ( document ready ), it seems that page can't reference jQuery library at all, but if I click on source link from error console, I can see in browser jQuery library's code. This is weird, because I have no error in IE or Chrome.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

**EDIT:**
Here's whole js code

```
$(function () {

        var digitCode;

        $('input[type=submit][id*=btnCancel]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            closeModalDialog('Cancel');
        });

        $("select[id*=ddlContacts]").on('change', function () {
            var contactID = $(this).val();
            if (parseInt(contactID) == 0) {
                $('span[id*=lblCEOTitle]').text("");
                return;
            }

            var data = { contactId: contactID };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "AddCompany.aspx/CeoTitle",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('span[id*=lblCEOTitle]').text(result.d);
                    $('input[type=hidden][id*=hdnFieldCeoTitle]').val(result.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you tried $(document).ready(function(){}); ??

Comment: Do a Ctrl+F5 on your FF.

Comment: @Alberto: That is the same, it won't make the difference if the error is with `$`. @michael: What about `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: no, cuz it doesn't recognize $, do you really think that changing syntax of document ready would help ?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté did like thousand times, cleared the cache, nothing helps

Comment: That's really weird then. Maybe try `console.log(typeof jQuery)` and check if it's defined after including the script.

Comment: Is the relative path correct? Do you see any 404 errors in the firebug?

Comment: @AlbertoLeón ok, let me try with jQuery, but I wonder, why it doesn't throw an exception in IE/Chrome ?

Comment: Perhaps is an error like a no closed element, or a javascript error, a no closed bracket, that IE and Chrome ignore, but firefox breaks, can you put on all code, please?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah, you were right, it's undefined typeof(jQuery)

Comment: Could you show us everything included in the HTML head tag?

Comment: I wonder if somehow there isn't an `async` attribute getting into your jQuery script tag? That was the problem last time I saw one of these questions.

Comment: @Tolis Not the whole head section, but here's what html was generated for jQuery reference
 
<script type="text/jscript" src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

may type="text/jscript" instead of type="text/javascript" cause the problem ?

Comment: JScript is a Microsoft-specific implementation of the ECMAScript. Yeah, try with text/javascript.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Nope, I don't have any asyc in jquery reference. You can see it in my previous comment.

Comment: From what I remember, Firefox usually discards scripts if the server sends a MIME type different than the one in the `type` of the script tag. If you're writing in HTML5, you can just skip the `type` attribute safely. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Well, the problem is, this is how I referenced jQuery from code

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

and it was rendered as type="text/jscript" instead.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté nope, it's not HTML5 unfortunately, and I just checked up with Chrome, in Chrome reference gets rendered exactlly the same way, and it works without any exceptions. Can this be Firefox specific problem ?

Comment: @michael moore your issue is the rendering of the script tag as `type=text/jscript` fix that and you wont have any problems.

Comment: I don't have experience with Sharepoint so I can't say if it's related, but there have been many bugs rising on FF lately. Might be worth a report on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: what about function parseInt? Perhaps you use it with a jquery call inside? If yes, you should declare inside ready event, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you work offline, you should let a CDN host these files for your users. Doing so has several advantages over hosting jQuery on your server(s): decreased latency, increased parallelism, and better caching. For more details check out this article : http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

This also saves some trouble (pathfile management, corrupt files, bad versions etc.) one of which you have just encountered now.

Comment: He's using Sharepoint, that means the most likely scenario is an intranet application, so an external CDN could be problematic. Still a good practice and it can be done internally

Comment: I was not aware of that, anyway.. I'm sure this will be useful for others.

Comment: well, this is weird, cuz I tried this, but it didn't help, however, I changed reference to CDN once again, and it started to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a bit of content about the webpage (eg: is it ASP.NET?)
Is the script reference correctly resolved? (you can check with firebug if the script is loaded)
Are you using any other javascript framework that may be confliting with jquery, ensuring $ is not defined?

Comment: This should not have been clicked as not useful as there are many scenarios where the technology involved causes the problem. You shouldn't mark an answer as not useful unless you know what you are talking about.

Comment: Well, Sharepoint and Firefox, DO have issues, despite what Microsoft says. Did you check if the script is loaded with firebug? Also, try the full URL not just the relative, maybe firefox doesn't like the URL startint with /

Comment: @CarlosGrappa full URL didn't help, could you share links on the topic ? ( FF doesn't work well with SharePoint )

Comment: @michaelmoore just google for it, some things aren't supported, others require some configuration (NTLM for example). If you run with firebug, do you see the jquery library script loaded? also, try alert($());

Comment: @CarlosGrappa yes, request for jQuery library returns 200OK ( in firebug ), in console, typeof(jQuery) returns undefined, typeof($) return function, it's really weird, why is this problem in Firefox ONLY.

Comment: @michaelmoore how odd. can you see if $().jquery returns a value? i thinks it should return the jquery version. Maybe a the root site level there is another javascript library causing issues